# How to remove html-tags in String value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use flutter widget Text() for displaying data which comes from API. For example, I got this string with html-content

```
String test = "List: <li> One;<li> Two;<li> Three.";
```

My widget with this variable:

```
Text(test)
```

Is there a way to remove all html-tags from String value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension should do it

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String stripHtml() => replaceAll(RegExp(r'<[^>]*>|&[^;]+;'), '');
}
```

Then use it like

```
Text(test.stripHtml())
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove html tags from a string you can use this code:

```
final text = 'List: <li> One;<li> Two;<li> Three.';
text = text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'<.*?>'), '');
```

You can change the `RegExp` according to your needs.